# PHP is including relative to the URL path and not the file path, how do you change this?

Tags: php, include-path

I have a PHP file /a/b/file.php with the line

```
require("../connect.php");
```

In connect.php there is a line

```
require("../config.inc.php");
```

This all works fine on my local server. There are a bunch of files using connect.php and they all work fine too.

However on the hosting site /a/b/file.php throws an error:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 
'../config.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in
/******/connect.php on line 3
```

I suspect that even though connect.php is in another folder, it's looking for it relative to /a/b. Is there a php.ini setting to change this?

Comment: Where is config.php located? What does your local include path look like?

Comment: config.inc.php is located in my root htdocs folder. include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php.

Comment: The lazy solution is adding the root htdocs folder to the include path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use something like:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."connect.php");
```

This way you will avoid problems like when you develop an app on a Unix-Like system and deploy it on a Windows systems, or viceversa.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Just to point out though that you need another DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR before the ".."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a php.ini setting, but usually I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for my included files.

`require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/relative/to/document_root/file.php";`

There are some cases where a relative path is better, but most of the time the files you want to include will stay in the same dir.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I personally make a file called `global.php` (which is in the `root` directory of the project) where I `define()` a constant, include libs and so on.

```
<?php
// ...
define('APP_INCLUDE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) .'/');
// ...
?>
```

Afterwards I include that file in all other files located in the same directory (e.g. index.php with `require('global.php')`. Now that everything is executed at that directory level you can use the constant `APP_INCLUDE_DIR` in every file which gets included.

```
<?php
require('global.php');

// ...
require_once(APP_INCLUDE_DIR .'a/b/c/connect.php');
?>
```

And in `a/b/c/connect.php` you could write for example

```
<?php
// ...
require_once(APP_INCLUDE_DIR .'a/b/config.inc.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your **include_path** in your PHP.ini file.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

For example, on my local server (XAMPP) it looks like this: `include_path   .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR

You can do a phpinfo() to find out also.